# jquery page navigation dynamic js load issue

Tags: jquery, html, cordova, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-ajax

I am using page navigation and for that i am using .live pageshow event like this

```
$('#watchlist').live('pageshow', function(event) {
        watchList();
    });
```

it is giving correct result as i expect but if i want to add any javascript file on that templates, can i do that so that i can use other functionality for perticular templates.

I just want to load dynamic templates with js on that templates not all the js file on index page becoz it is conflicting somewhere

Comment: Use `.on` instead of `.live`. For js indexes, add them inside `<body>` to be loaded.

Comment: i used some function by using this i can load css and js on templates but again if i am going to another templates , it is coming with js and css which i have included in last templates....can u solve this issue for me

Comment: let's say you load a page with id `stuff`, when you navigate away, remove that page. `$(document).on('pagehide', '#stuff', function() { $(this).remove(); });` try this.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand you. Can you describe with more details what do you want to do? What is an expected behavior?

Comment: $(...).on is not a function when adding this with my page id

Comment: I just want page navigation with different html page including different js and css file thats it..

Answer (score 1):

## Intro

This answer is a response to the comment

> "I just want page navigation with different html page including
> different js and css file thats it.. ".

To understand this answer lets discuss how jQuery Mobile works. It uses ajax to load other pages into the **`DOM`**.

First page is loaded normally. Its **`HEAD`** and **`BODY`** is loaded into the **`DOM`**, and they are there to await other content. When second page is loaded, only its **`BODY`** content is loaded into the **`DOM`**.

## Solutions

There are 2 solutions here:

#### Solution 1

In your second page, and every other page, move your **`SCRIPT`**, **`LINK`** and **`STYLE`** tags into the **`BODY`** content, like this:

```
<body>
    <script>
        // Your javascript will go here
    </script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="some.css" />
    // And rest of your HTML content
</body>
```

This is a quick solution but to me this is an ugly solution.

#### Solution 2

Use **rel="external"** in your buttons and every elements you are using to change page. Because of it ajax is not going to be used for page loading and your jQuery Mobile app will behave like a normal web application.

```
<a href="#second" class="ui-btn-right" rel="external">Next</a>
```

Official documentation, look for a chapter: **[Linking without Ajax](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/pages/page-links.html)**. Unfortunately mobile app will lose page transitions because of this.